# Error sending Titanium app to Xcode output

Tags: ios, titanium-sdk

Good afternoon,

I am trying to compile my application to send it to the Xcode for uploading to the app store.

But I get always this error (image).

Does anyone know what can it be?

In the past I was able to send it to the app store, but now it started giving this error.

Xcode version: 14.3

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A workaround is to use Xcode 14.2 or try https://github.com/tidev/titanium-sdk/actions/runs/5033201921 (you'll need to be logged in and at the bottom you can find a nightly build artifact).

In case you app contains a space you could also use the i18n way to name your app (check the documentation) but that one should also be fixed with the nightly build.

If you have an error (like invalid certificate) you can use `-l trace` to build your app and check above that for a different error.